# "JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to NodaTime.Instant" NodaTime issue with ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Page web application

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, nodatime, json-serialization

In ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Page pure front end web application I received the below error.

Installed the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="4.7.2" />
<PackageReference Include="EnumExtensions.System.Text.Json" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Also set this in Startup:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
  .AddJsonOptions(options =>
  {
      // options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
      // options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
      // options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;

      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport(null, true, true, true, true));
      //options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(NodaConverters.IntervalConverter);
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(NodaConverters.InstantConverter);
  })
  .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
  {
      options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Login", "");
  });
```

> JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to NodaTime.Instant. Path: $.data[0].created_at | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 261.
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable<TClass, TDeclaredProperty, TRuntimeProperty, TConverter>.OnRead(ref ReadStack state, ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ref ReadStack state, ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, ref Utf8JsonReader reader, ref ReadStack readStack)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(string json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(string json, JsonSerializerOptions options)

Here's the snippet of data it's trying to deserialize. If I switch from Instant to DateTimeOffset, it works "instantly".

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": "2020-08-09T22:10:26.274672Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-13T02:22:02.640871Z",
        }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "size": 20,
    "count": 1,
    "total": 1,
    "success": true,
    "message": null
}
```

Note: this JSON data is a result of serialization of an object that does include CreatedAt & UpdatedAt properties of the type (NodaTime)Instant. I confirm it works nicely with an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC API application.

Not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonSerializerOptions` cannot be set at global in the current version of `System.Text.Json`. This can be resolved by building options right where you need them:

```cs
var jsonString = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"f606942c-4740-46a7-be6f-66ceb38c530b\",\"created_at\":\"2020-08-09T22:10:26.274672Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-08-13T02:22:02.640871Z\"}],\"page\":1,\"size\":20,\"count\":1,\"total\":1,\"success\":true,\"message\":null }";
    
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport(null, true, true, true, true));

var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(jsonString, options);

    
public enum SampleType
{
    TYPE_0,
    TYPE_1
}

public class Sample
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; } = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public Instant CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public Instant UpdateAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public SampleType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IEnumerable<Sample> Data { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public int Size { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```